# What is the best data sharing mechanism between two iOS apps if the data to be shared is huge and the apps can have different app id prefixes?

Tags: ios, data-sharing

I recently have a use case where i need to share huge amounts of data between two iOS apps. The two apps can have different app id prefixes. What could be the best ways to do it?

I have explored some of the options but either some of them need a common app id prefix, some are not very secure and some require additional user interactions.

Suggestions, thoughts welcome. Thanks!!

I have explored the following options -

1. UIDocumentInteractionController
2. UIActivityViewController

Both of these I can't use because I do not want to have additional user interaction.

1. Shared Keychain Access - This cant be used as the apps can have different 10 digit seed prefix

I was contemplating on using URL Schemes but I wonder if there is a limit to the amount of data that can be passed using URL scheme.

I also got to know about DocumentProvider extension with iOS 8 but did not get a clear picture on whether it will also involve additional user interaction or not. Also, is it mandatory to use iCloud with DocumentProvider.

Comment: Please define "huge".

Comment: Update your question with what you options you have explored and point out which ones you can't use or don't want to use.

Comment: @HAS, it can be some 3k to 4k strings with each string being of the format "SR36773711141".

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, we have following ways data can be shared across two different iOS applications:

1. UIDocumentInteractionController
2. UIActivityViewController
3. Shared Keychain Access
4. Custom URL Scheme
5. Web Service

For sharing large amount of data, Web Service based solution makes sense but with an overhead of web service implementation and availability of network.